# Loading Resources Before Starting The Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, loading

My game's `MainActivity` set content view to a GamePanel that extends SurfaceView
and in my GamePanel class i have a-lot of objects (Background, Buttons, enemies, Background music, etc..) that create on starting the Activity.
the problem is: on testing when i start my `MainActivity` all i'm getting a black screen! and sometimes the app crash,
i think why this is happening because i'm creating too many things at once,Right?
so my question is: How can i load some of these objects or Resources before i start this activity? and would it work? and my game performance better?
-If you want my code i will post it!
Thanks.

Comment: So what errors do you see in the LogCat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading a lot of resources you should be doing it in a background thread where possible to prevent `ANR` (Application Not Responding). Optionally you may show some loading UI in the Activity itself. One way to accomplish that would be using `AsyncTask`: doing heavy loading in `doInBackground()` and managing the UI in `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()`

Comment: I agree with Sam, you can also check for AsyncTask example here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Comment: Lets say i want to load my Background images before the activity starts, How can i do that?

Comment: Load resources and start activity afterwards. But there's is absolutely no reason to do that imho